# Java - What's the difference of double-clicking and running from Terminal for opening a .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, terminal

I am using a Java-based application (a .jar file) to access a website for online discussion. And recently I've experienced some weird difference between running the application by double-clicking (on both Mac and Ubuntu) and running `java -jar client.jar` from Terminal. When I open the client by double-clicking, it will not allow me to log in, while everything works fine if I run it from Terminal.

I know the description might be too vague, but I just wonder whether there is any general difference between these two ways of running .jar file. Thanks!

My Java environment is shown below:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It really depends on what the OS is configured to do when double clicking a jar.  Mine is configured to open it in winrar (I tend to open jars more often than run them).

Comment: It is configured to open with Oracle Java 7 Runtime on my computer. So it should not be that problem. And the client opens correctly, showing the interface just fine. Any other possible config problem you see? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that some login script is running when you are in the terminal, such that your PATH or CLASSPATH is different, and thus the operational environment is different in both cases?

Alternatively, I don't know how either Ubuntu or Mac set their working directories when you double click a file, but perhaps that's a clue.

Comment: You told us what *doesn't* happen (and I assume that you expect this to happen) when double-clicking. It will be helpful if you also tell us what *does* happen.

Comment: Basically rigiht now in Ubuntu 14.04 double click with set the user.dir to /home/user instead of the parent directory of the jar which is what the terminal will do. Note that on windows double click sets user.dir to the parent of the jar which is more intuitive and how the terminal will behave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the method used to invoke the program, the current working directory might change. When running via `java -jar` the working directory is set by the terminal, easily identifiable by the prompt. When double-clicking, the directory defaults to the user's home directory. A quick test for demonstration:

```
public class TestWorkingDirectory { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

Assuming the JAR is located in `/home/test/Applications`, it will show the this path when running from terminal. When double-clicking, it's just `/home/test`. Therefore the path could be identical using both methods (when archive is located in `~`), but not necessarily - a difficulty when trying to debug / reproduce abnormal behavior.

Comment: Double click behavior on Ubuntu 14.04 is probably a bug since it is more intuitive that the current directory should be the parent of the jar directory. That is how double click is implemented on windows 10. This allows double click to take advantage of relative paths.

Comment: Is it possible to change the directory from home to where the file is?